# xcode c++ debugger shows some, not all of entries in array

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

So xcode debugger is being a bit odd. I have a class with an array of pointers.

```
class node {
public: entry **entries;
public: node **children;
public: node *parent;
public: int currentsize;
public: int maxSize;

public: int childrensize;


    node(int size)
    {
        maxSize=size;
        children= new node *[size+1];
        entries=new entry *[size];
        currentsize=0;
        childrensize=0;
    }
```

and then just calling node n= new node(3); at the beginning of the main method.

If I set a break point on that maxSize line, the debugger seems to have already made up its mind. It shows 2 entries, and 6 children even if the actual number of each is more or less than that. 
See example image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50013882/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-13%20at%202.15.57%20PM.png
(I am fairly new and apparently can't directly post images)

Any advice on handling this? I don't think I have a problem with the actual code in this regard, but I am not sure.That image is after I initilized things, but even when the node has only started being created, it looks like that but with null for everything.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the value of `maxSize` when you single step *past* the assignment line `maxSize=size` ? Is it the value you passed as a parameter (but not shown here) now correctly assigned? You may want to consider using a member initialization list, btw, and I strongly advise [**RAII**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) containers such as `std::vector` and smart pointers.

Comment: Its decided with an input to the class constructor(I left that out to make the code minimal) but I tried hard coding it and got the same result. Ill look into those, but I need to solve this with regular pointers for now

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is the value of `maxSize` **after** you step over the assignment line. Is it the value you passed as a parameter (or hard-assigned, matters now which)? You may also check to make sure your debugging a debug-build; not a release-build.

Comment: I did answer it, sorry if I was unclear. Max size is a parameter that is passed. However, when trying to debug this, i tried hard coding it as well. Hard coding it did not change things at all.
And as far as I can tell I am on debug build, though I can't say for sure. I am using the default Xcode c++ template.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to ask this any differently.  And you *still* have not answered my question. *What is the value of the `maxSize` variable **after** the assignment line is executed (i.e. after you have stepped **over** it) once*? Until such time as you purposefully assign to a member (assuming it is a member; we don't know that either) it will retain its constructed value (be it default or specified). Posting a minimal, **compilable** example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) would greatly add to your question. Knowing what the code is *supposed* to do would also help.

Comment: size can be any int, but if you need an option, lets say 3, or 10.
As for being compilable, I am trying to keep things minimal because last time I made something compilable it was instantly locked for being too long,

Comment: Part of an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that is **is** compilable. Surely you can create an MCVE. And I given up asking my question. I dunno if there is a language barrier or what the problem is. I didn't ask what value `size` had. Given `maxSize=size;`
 is the core of your posted original question and its seemingly odd value it is acquiring (I stand by my suspicion because you didn't actually execute the line of code that performs the assignment) I would have hoped asking what value `maxSize` had **after** stepping over **that** assignment line would be answerable.

Comment: The value is what you would expect- the line executes. If size=3, maxSize is 3. I believe the issue is with my IDE, not the code which is what I am asking for help with.

Comment: OK. If the object you're debugging is in a loop or part of a repeatable call stack it is possible that your members are still laying on old values until such time as they're assigned once again. If your object lays down on the same memory region as a prior object (that has since been destroyed by ending something like a loop iteration) it is entirely plausible the values those members obtain are, in fact, from the prior object. That is sheer speculation as  we don't know what your real code looks like. Did you try using a member-initializer list (which is where these should be anyway)?

Comment: No, it is not a part of a loop. The values shown (the first two entries and the first 6 children nodes) do show correctly- that is, if I say node.entries[0]=someValue, someValue shows immediately. But if I do the same for entries[2], the debugger shows no change, since it is not displaying anything beyond entries[1]. The code shown is a constructor at the very beginning of the program. 
I don't know exactly what you mean by member-initializer list, but the values are added later in the program.

Comment: Ok. *Now* I think I understand. A dynamic pointer such as the one you're assigning, then populating array slots therein, is somewhat odd in Xcode's debugger. The running debugger doesn't really know how many items you actually allocated. Does that make sense? So it doesn't know you, say, allocated an array of 10 `entry*`. All it knows is that `entries` points to a sequence of some number of `entry*`. So absolutely, your assessment its an oddity of Xcode is fairly accurate. Perhaps a `std::vector<entry*>`, or even `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<entry>>` if you really want the full monte.

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way though to just tell Xcode to look for, say, 15 entries? I don't know why it arbitrarily chose 2 for entries, and 6 for children but it makes debugging  much harder. I would rather continue using pointers, since I don't fully understand vectors yet and don't want to add further complications to my code.
Whatever caused it to make that decision for 2 and 6 entries shown must be modifiable somehow right? I see an edit summery format option when I right click and thats my best guess, but don't know how to use it\

Comment: There *is* a way to do it. Ultimately its all just switches submitted to lldb, then ripped apart and pretty-formatted for the little tree (which can get *very* annoying). The debugger will *not* do it for you automagically, however. In the past I've had to add convoluted expressions such as, `(Object *(*)[N])pp`, where `Object` is your type, `N` is the number of items allocated (and must be constant), and `pp` is the pointer to pointer. And yes, its hideous. On that regard the integrated debugging features of Xcode aren't exactly friendly.

Comment: Btw, not that it is going to solve your world of problems right now, but assuming there is a need for dynamic allocation of each element as you're doing (polymorphism, etc), a vector solution would be something [**like this**](http://ideone.com/H2XTmP). As a bonus, you get [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) semantics, etc. And best of all (in your case) the Xcode debugger has formatters for `std::vector`, so you get your browsing N elements as well. When you're not in the hot seat on your current project, its definitely worth a look. Best of luck.